# How can I escape special characters that is entered in a function which contains awk command?

Tags: bash, awk, xmllint

To make this problem simple to demonstrate, I made a fake xml file like this.

```
<abc>
      <spirit:addressBlock>
        <spirit:name>cmn700_registers</spirit:name>
          <def>
          </def>
      </spirit:addressBlock>
</abc>
```

And I want to print lines containing pattern `<spirit:name>` inside a block of lines, the block begining with the pattern `<spirit:addressBlock>` and ending with `</spirit:addressBlock>`. I defined a function in .bash_aliase like this.

```
function SearchPatInBlk {
awk "/$1/{inblk=1} inblk==1&&/$2/{inblk=0} inblk==1&&/$3/{print \$0}" $4
}
```

So the first argument and second argument is the block start and end pattern, third argument is the pattern I want to print the line with and the fourth argument is the xml filename. And then I gave this command at the bash shell.

```
SearchPatInBlk <spirit:addressBlock> </spirit:addressBlock> <spirit:name> ../../ab21/ab21_cmn700_new10_clst/build/ab21_cmn700/logical/cmn700/ipxact/cmn700_ab21.xml
```

Of course this gives me an error.

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

So I tried putting some escape characters (`\`) before <,>,/ but it doesn't work. How should I do it?

Comment: Do you have to do it in awk, sed? Why not use xml tools like `xmllint` ?

Comment: @anubhava Hi, I've installed xmllint just now, and searched the help but it's not clear yet. but what is the command (if it's just simple)? I don't have much time reading about the new tool...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a true XML parser would be better than a general purpose text processor like `awk`. But if you absolutely need `awk` there are several things to fix.

- Quote your pattern strings.
- Escape regex operators in your pattern strings.
- Pass your pattern strings to `awk` as `awk` variables, not as parts of the `awk` script.
- Use the `regex,regex` `awk` range pattern.

Optionally you could also use more accurate regex and, if your `awk` is GNU `awk`, mark the patterns as regex constants (`@/.../`):

```
function SearchPatInBlk {
  awk -v v1="$1" -v v2="$2" -v v3="$3" 'v1,v2 {if($0 ~ v3) print}' "$4"
}

SearchPatInBlk '@/^[[:space:]]*[<]spirit:addressBlock[>][[:space:]]*$/' \
  '@/^[[:space:]]*[<][/]spirit:addressBlock[>][[:space:]]*$/' \
  '@/[<]spirit:name[>]' file
```

Comment: Thanks again! That works.  (I tried SearchPatInBlk '/<spirit:addressBlock>/' '/</spirit:addressBlock>' '<spirit:name>' test.xml for the command.)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use text processors like `sed` or `awk` on structured data. Use a (command-line) XML processor instead. Here are some options:

(Note that the sample given by itself isn't valid XML as it doesn't declare the `spirit` namespace, which makes the elements `spirit:addressBlock` and `spirit:name` lack their binding, and eventually trips up some of these processors, so you might want to add something along the lines of `<abc … xmlns:spirit="…" … >` to the sample. But if your actual document does declare them properly, you'll be fine using any of these.

Using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

- requires namespaces to be properly declared, so won't run with the sample given
- the `select` (or `sel`) command makes `xmlstarlet` perform a query on the input, and the `--template` (or `-t`) flag starts a new template with the `--var` option importing a quoted (hence the `@Q`) value into a variable, and the `-value-of` (or `-v`) option evaluating an XPath expression used for extraction and printing

```bash
SearchPatInBlk() {
  xmlstarlet sel -t --var fst="${1@Q}" --var snd="${2@Q}" \
    -v '//*[name() = $fst]//*[name() = $snd]/text()' "$3"
}

SearchPatInBlk spirit:addressBlock spirit:name input.xml
```

- you could even omit the namespaces in your function call by testing against the nodes' `local-name()` instead of their `name()` (but properly declared namespaces in the document are still required)

```bash
SearchPatInBlk() {
  xmlstarlet sel -t --var fst="${1@Q}" --var snd="${2@Q}" \
    -v '//*[local-name() = $fst]//*[local-name() = $snd]/text()' "$3"
}

SearchPatInBlk addressBlock name input.xml
```

Using [libxml/xmllint](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/wikis/home):

- also requires namespaces to be properly declared, so won't run with the sample given
- with the `--xpath` option, this also uses an XPath expression to query and extract, but has no means to import external values, so the function's arguments are injected directly into the expression (note the double quotes around it)

```bash
SearchPatInBlk() {
  xmllint --xpath "//*[name() = ${1@Q}]//*[name() = ${2@Q}]/text()" "$3"
}

SearchPatInBlk spirit:addressBlock spirit:name input.xml
```

- the change from `name()` to `local-name()` in order to allow for omitting the namespaces in the function call can be applied here as well (with the namespaces still required to be properly declared in the document)

```bash
SearchPatInBlk() {
  xmllint --xpath \
    "//*[local-name() = ${1@Q}]//*[local-name() = ${2@Q}]/text()" "$3"
}

SearchPatInBlk addressBlock name input.xml
```

Using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

- doesn't care about namespace declarations, so indeed also runs with the sample given (but namespaces, if present, still need to be spelled out when referencing nodes by name, e.g. `spirit:name`)
- the `--arg` option imports values into variables, and the `--raw-output` (or `-r`) flag decodes the result value into raw text (as otherwise it would be JSON-encoded, because under the hood it uses the JSON processor `jq`)

```bash
SearchPatInBlk() {
  xq --arg fst "$1" --arg snd "$2" -r \
    '..[$fst]? | ..[$snd]? | arrays[] // values' "$3"
}

SearchPatInBlk spirit:addressBlock spirit:name input.xml
```

Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

- completely ignores the usage of namespaces in names, so it also runs with the sample given (they are actually eliminated there altogether, so spelling them out in fact causes an error)
- importing values is done via environment variables, and interpreting the input as XML is determined by the input file's extension (otherwise explicitly provide the `--input-format xml` (or `-px`) option), while the output is deliberately encoded as YAML using the `--output-format yaml` (or `-oy`) option to unquote the results

```bash
SearchPatInBlk() {
  fst="$1" snd="$2" yq -oy \
    '.. | .[strenv(fst)]? | .. | [] + .[strenv(snd)]? | .[]' "$3"
}

SearchPatInBlk addressBlock name input.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<abc>
      <spirit:addressBlock>
        <spirit:name>cmn700_registers</spirit:name>
          <def>
          </def>
      </spirit:addressBlock>
</abc>' |
```

---

```
 mawk 'gsub(/^[^<]*|[^>]+$/,_, $!(NF *= (NF % 2) < (2 < NF)))' \
            ORS= FS='[<][/]' OFS='</' RS='spirit:addressBlock[>]'
```

---

```
     1  <spirit:name>cmn700_registers</spirit:name>
     2            <def>
     3            </def>
```